# Proper atomic HashMap snapshot (checkpoint)?

Tags: java, dictionary, atomic, snapshot

Given a `HashMap` that's large enough and accessed (modified) frequently, how can I create an instantaneous snapshot (checkpoint)?

Is there a way to avoid (shallow) copying at all? Like COW for mem page or file system.

If there isn't, how can I make sure that modifications during snapshot process will not affect the snapshot?

The worst solution is lock writing before snapshot done, or making a shallow copy for every write, but that's the worst solution.

Comment: You want a [deep copy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_copying#Deep_copy)? If so, say so.

Comment: Perhaps you should be using a transactional database. Such as [Postgres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostgreSQL) with its implementation of [multiversion concurrency control (MVCC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiversion_concurrency_control). For an embedded, pure Java database consider [H2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H2_(DBMS)), with [its MVCC implementation](http://h2database.com/html/advanced.html#mvcc).